# jquery dock effect on image map area

Tags: jquery, html

i'm just wondering if it is possible to add a dock effect on an image map area.

Please give me an example or some suggestions..very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is theoretically possible with canvas, but you'd have to do a lot of low level graphical manipulation with the mapped image. It would be much simpler to reevaluate your approach and do something similar to jqDock:

http://www.wizzud.com/jqdock/